# c# Webservice on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm a bit out of my depth and haven't found the answer I need from Google, so could do with some advice.

I have a website that currently has some functionality build in.

I now find myself needing to create a second website containing the same functionality.

In order to do this the proper way, I want to create a webservice and access it from both sites. I've created a new solution and the webservice so far.

On my development machine, I can browse to the webservice.

The question is when I move this webservice to the live server, will it need it's own IP address, domain, or both? Or can it reside on the local server and be accessed in the same way as I would on my development machine?

The webservice does not need to be accessed from outside the server.

I'm a little unclear and its not easy to test in a live environment.

All help appreciated.

Comment: it can be accessed with the domain name with alias name , suppose your domain is `x.com` you can create the `webservice.x.com` for services which can be useful !!

Comment: @Webruster - for clarity, would I still create the webservice as a separate solution?

Comment: i would say seperate website or project!

Answer (score 0):

A web service works in exactly the same way as a website, only instead of returning HTML, it returns JSON/XML or similar.  You'll need to host it on a web server, but if you only need it to be locally accessible, you can set the web server up to bind to localhost (127.0.0.1 in IP4) either on the default port (80) if nothing is already using it or on a different port (eg.12380 where it would be addressed as http://localhost:12380).

Most web servers can bind to anything that comes in on a specific IP address that isn't otherwise allocated or they can recognise which site to serve based on the host name that has been requested.  nb. the host name isn't sent automatically by (TCP/)IP - the browser, or in this case web service client will sent an HTTP request header to let the server know which site to serve.

If you have sufficient control over the server, you can also create an entry in the hosts file to use in place of a domain name (eg. webservice maps to 127.0.0.1) and then set up your web server to bind to that.